# I want to know how popUntill and pushAndRemoveUntill will work as per the descibed code

Tags: flutter, navigation, flutter-navigation

I want to understand how both the commands will behave:

1. Here i have popped untill route first, then remove that route too and pushes a new route.

So ultimately removing all the routes and pushing Screen1 as first route.

```
Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) => route.isFirst);
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>const Screen1()));
```

2. Here I am using pushAndRemoveUntil to remove till first route and then push to Screen1.

What I want to know is will it pop all the routes including first and then push Sceen1. (Exectly same as case 1)

Or will it pop till firstRoute(keeping first route) and then push Sceen1 onto the first route (keeping first route in the stack)

```
Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>const Screen1()),(route) => route.isFirst,);
```

Comment: why don't you check for yourself by running the codes? what's the issue here!

Answer (score 0):

For first case, you will pop all routes until your predicate return true. So, when first route is the upper one in the stack, `popuntil` stop popping routes.

In fact you will at this step only the first route. When you execute pushReplacement, your new route become the first one.

For second case, `pushAndRemoveUntil` will not do the same.

First, `pushAndRemoveUntil` push your new route and once done, it will remove all previous routes in the stack unitl the predicate become true.

Thus, after `pushAndRemoveUntil` execution, you will have your first route preserved and the the (current) new route.

You can replace `route.isFirst` by `false` to remove the first route too.